# Kill command keeps killing me

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to kill all Iron Golems around me, and I thought "Simple, this command should be enough!"

`/kill @e[type=IronGolem,r=100]`

Whenever I run that, it just kills myself though. What have I got wrong with the command? Or is it an issue because I'm in 1.7.10 (for mods)?

Comment: 1.7.10 does not have an `@e` selector, also it does not work (in 1.7.10, only in 1.8+).

Comment: @aytimothy You should make that an answer

Comment: @MrLemon But it doesn't explain why the `@e` selector works like an `@a` or `@p` selector. | If I'd knew why, I would've posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prior to 1.8, the `/kill` command does not have an optional target argument. From the [1.8 change log](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.8):

> - `/kill`

- Can be followed by a target selector.
- Example: `/kill @e[type=!Player]`

In 1.7.10 (and earlier versions), it will always kill the player running the command.

Answer (score 2):

The version you are using causes this.

The `@e` target selector was added in 1.8.0, therefore you can't do this in 1.7.10.

You can view the wiki post about version [1.8 here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.8).

I googled a bit in hope to find a mod that allows killing all mobs in a specific type for 1.7.10, but I was unable to find any.

Comment: -1 Nice try. | Does not have an valid explaination why `@e` can behave like `@a` or `@p`.

Comment: @aytimothy maybe because I don't know why it can? However, you are free to edit. Side note: this was not derived from your comment.

Answer (score 2):

CoFH Core actually does what you want for 1.7.10.

The command is `/cofh killall [entity]`.

Answer (score 0):

`/kill @e[type=VillagerGolem]` should work.